# Trying to show ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I am trying to show a ListFragment. I think I have everything set up correctly but no matter what I try I get a RuntimeException: Unable to start Activity. I have been searching and debugging for a few days now and havent came up with an answer yet. Here is the code I have so far. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the method that starts the Activity:

```
private void populateList(ArrayList<String> list) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TipListActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(INTENT_KEY, list);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the Activity that the previous method starts:

```
public class TipListActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /*************** FIELDS ***************************/

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    /*************** OVERRIDDEN METHODS ***************/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tip_list_fragment_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        arrayList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(TipActivity.INTENT_KEY);
    }
}
```

Here is tip_list_fragment_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:name=".TipListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_activity"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is TipListFragment:

```
public class TipListFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new TipListActivity().arrayList);

        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
        savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

And finally here is list_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp">

 <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/textv"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="@string/app_name"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the stack trace:

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.tipcalculator/com.app.tipcalculator.TipListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at com.app.tipcalculator.TipListActivity.onCreate(TipListActivity.java:28)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     ... 11 more
07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment .TipListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:359)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:262)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     ... 21 more
07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .TipListFragment

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:381)

07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083):     ... 24 more

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the correct id for your list.  You have `android:id="@+id/list"`.

A ListFragment is looking for a very specific id.

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Make that change and you should see an improvement in your app behavior.

You might also move your code in the `onCreate` of `TipListFragment` to `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: Thanks I updated the id to that however I'm still having the same problem :(

Comment: Try changing your `onCreate` in the `TipListFragment` to `onActivityCreated`... I think you may be trying to access data from the activity before it is fully up and running.

Comment: Sorry I still get the same thing. Are fragments supposed to be declared in the manifest like activities?

Comment: I see a couple more things that look odd to me... the `new` in the call to your adapter, seems circular... you start `TipListActivity`, which starts `TipListFragment` by virtue of you calling it out in the XML which then calls a *new* `TipsListActivity` which then...  etc.  Try getting rid of the `new` bit and declare ArrayList `public static` in the FragmentActivity.

Comment: Hey thanks Barak you were right about trying to access data before its fully up and running. I move the code from the onCreate (and onActivityCreated as you mentioned trying) to onCreateView and it works. Yes I dont plan on using new to access the ArrayList I just did that for troubleshooting purposes. TipListFragment will be an inner class of TipListActivity so I can easily access the ArrayList. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not done this before, just registered, my two pence worth is that you cant seem to use ".NAME" in the xml layout, the error points you too line 7 in the xml:

```
07-01 00:41:37.932: E/AndroidRuntime(6083): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

Around this line approx:

```
android:name=".TipListFragment"
```

Whatever your package is it should be complete:

```
android:name="com.all.bits.required.TipListFragment"
```

Android Dev uses full naming, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding as an example:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"...
```

Not sure how far this will help you but will move onto the next error at least, if there is one :)

Cheers

Jacko